# Installing angular-cli on Windows Behind Proxy Server

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I am currently building Angular 2 demos from behind a corporate proxy server with known issues for blocking both NPM and TypeScript 'typings' installs. While I have been able to work around these issues with proxy server settings, I'm a little unsure what to do about the latest issue.

Whenever I try to install angular-cli globally:

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

or even locally to a directory with an existing **npm init** setup (including package.json file):

```
npm install angular-cli --save
```

I receive the following error (all local paths replaced with ):

**angular-cli npm install error**

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 
'C:\Users\<PATH>\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\babel-runtime' ->
'C:\Users\<PATH>\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\.babel-runtime.DELETE'
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm ERR! Please try running this command as root/Administrator.
```

Anyone else having issues (or a solution) to this particular user permission issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `running this command as root/Administrator`? If yes, try to delete `C:\Users\<PATH>\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\babel-runtime`manually and launch your command again.

Comment: @StephaneM since the introduction of Angular2 Final Release, installation of angular-cli behind a corporate proxy doesn't seem to be an issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To load npm modules behind a proxy server you need to type in following commands in the node.js terminal:

1. npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
2. npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

Comment: And to check your current config:
1. npm config get proxy
2. npm config get https-proxy
@Devaarth thx

Comment: Actually , NPM installs proxy info in Drive/Users/%USER%/.npmrc  file

Answer (score 6):

1. Download and install Nodejs
   https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Check your proxy setting. Based on your organization it will be change. If proxy not define you need to define your proxy setting in to LAN setting.

[image]

3. Run CMD as Administrator enter the command

   npm config set https-proxy http://10.10.20.60:80

[image]

4. If you are going to install in to a remote PC or you need windows Active Directory credential for installation.

[image]

[image]

5. run angular cli command:

   ***npm i –g angular-cli***

[image]

Comment: What if proxy is not there?

Comment: @PathikVejani without proxy you can run command directly : npm i –g angular-cli

Comment: @PathikVejani remove special character from your password

Answer (score 2):

I was able install angular-cli behind the corporate proxy, Need to follow the below steps:

1. Install node/npm
2. Configure proxy for Nodejs like below :

   Run the below commands

   npm config set proxy {your proxy server address}

   npm config set {your proxy server address}

3.Install "gitbash", as gitbash will help us download the packages from gitHub

4. Cofigure 'gitbash' proxy run the below command:

git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080

Then hit the final command:

npm install -g angular-cli@latest

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Windows Power Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=2560) which solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command with port.
npm config set https-proxy http://yours.com:1234

Answer (score -2):

I have had ongoing problems with this issue for some time now. However, after the Final Release of Angular 2 and the accompanying update to the **angular-cli** package, I have been able to download and install **angular-cli** globally with no issues on a Windows 64-bit computer using the Command Prompt behind a proxy.

Hope this helps someone!