# Angular CLI installation issue shows ENOTFOUND and proxy config not proper errors

Tags: angular, npm

While trying to install Angular CLI after installation of node js , with the following versions:

- npm version is 5.6.0
- node version is v8.11.2

[The following errors regarding code and errno ENOTFOUND,request to https://regisrty.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, problem related to network connectivity , behind proxy and to check if behind proxy the the proxy configurations are set properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mNoJ.png)

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351553/installing-angular-cli-on-windows-behind-proxy-server)

Comment: I have tried every solution given on that page and still wasn’t able to download Angular CLI

Comment: well where are trying to Install CLI on your Personal PC or Corporate PC?

Comment: actually both , and the error is the some on both of them.